# Using feature's one-to-many statistics as graduated color symbology in ArcGIS Online application?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, arcade, one-to-many

I've made a task oriented ArcGIS Online application that I like to improve: The application is about filling a numeric score field in a table for each row. Each row in the table is related to a feature service's layer row\feature.

How can I make the symbology of the related feature to be shown as a graduated color that is based on a statistic value (count, mean, sum etc.) of its related table rows?

---

I'm almost positive that the answer to this question can be achieved by using the [ArcGIS Arcade](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/) new expression option, when used in the [change style](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/change-style.htm) tab. The reason for this assumption, is I've already manged to so with the layer's pop-ups as specified [here](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-pop-ups.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_09B2E0D22072457AAC8D025377DD7CF9). So I think what I'm looking for now  is a syntax to represent this one-to-many relationship - something like this pseudocode:

> `// return the average values of feature's related rows from a numeric score field Average($feature.relationships\0\NumericFieldNameFomRelatedTable)`

--- *Things I've tried* ---

- 'Dive' quite deep in to the AGOL web map's interface.
- Try to migrate it to ArcGIS Pro and somehow to fetch the pop-up's expression
- find an alternative in web-appbuilder's widgets.

--- *Thing's I need to go a little deeper* ---

- [Arcade Expressions and You](https://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?id=dfe07fe13d154b67bbd7a38a2be90fd9#overview) examples.
- how to do this by python in ArcMap

Comment: I've raised this question in the ArcGIS forum and at the mean time it seems that there's no solution using Arcade.
https://community.esri.com/thread/214278-how-to-use-features-one-to-many-statistics-as-a-graduated-color-symbology-in-an-arcgis-online-application

Comment: Have you seen this page: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/style-numbers.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_1D8BD412F83148C6ABF315CA10111E66  which points to this example http://links.esri.com/arcgis-online-help/counts-amounts-color-example ?  Is this in any way what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Probably yes but haven't dug into it - thank's for pointing that out. Unfortunately the page and the example given, don't use any related data and therefore don't address my problem.

Comment: I had a similar requirement last year.  I ended up doing some client-side joining between the featurelayer and the related table (1:M)  The Seattle sample from this blog post helped me a lot  https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/js-api-arcgis/mapping/using-smart-mapping-in-custom-web-apps/